# How to direct 3 htmls in one html in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a html which has 3 divisions

```
 <div >
div related to profile
</div>

<div >
div related to settings
</div>

<div >
div related to password change
</div>
```

i want to create 3 individual templates,

1)profile
2)settings
3)password  change

so i want to call each template in my main template according to the condition,can anyone suggest me help for doing this.

Comment: Create three components?

Comment: your question is unclear....

Comment: @noodl,i edited my question

Comment: @jonrsharpe,can i do that without creating components i.e only with templates

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to create 3 components. Those will be your template, placed by the directive in your main template.

If you only need HTML, why don't you place the html inside the main template?

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {ProfileComponent} from './profile.component'
import {SettingsComponent} from './settings.component'
import {PasswordChangeComponent} from './change-password.component'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>

    <profile></profile>
    <settings></settings>
    <password></password>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'User'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, ProfileComponent, SettingsComponent, PasswordChangeComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Check this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KVLzIH3c1lxouzFZXyBp?p=preview)